# scala mongodb IN filter use

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongodb-query

I have been struggling with the Filters for MongoDB in the Scala mongo Driver. I am trying to get all documents in a collection where a specific string in the document is in a list of strings. I create a list of strings in Scala and then I build the query with the IN operator:

```
val find3 = in(EventItem, ListDelayedItems.toList)
```

According to the documentation, the in has two overloaded methods:

```
public static <TItem> Bson in(String fieldName,
                              TItem... values)
public static <TItem> Bson in(String fieldName,
                              Iterable<TItem> values)
```

The problem is, I have no idea how to construct Iterable values. If I pass the values as a list of values (see the first overloaded method),

```
in(EventItem, "ABCDE", "DEF", "ESO4SAP")
```

it works. This is what I see when I print the in operator filter

```
Operator Filter{fieldName='billing_event.action.resources.item', operator='$in', value=[ABCDE, DEF, ESO4SAP]}
```

But as soon as I try to pass a list in the second parameter to use the second overloaded method, it does not work. The list I am trying to use to filter is dynamic. I have tried scala Lists, ListBuffers, java.util.Lists but every time I use the variable like this:

```
in(EventItem, ListValidItems)
```

It stops working. I defined the ListValidItems as every collection I know, but when I see the log I see this:

```
Operator Filter{fieldName='billing_event.action.resources.item', operator='$in', value=[List(ABCDE, EFGH, ESO4SAP)]}
```

So it changed from 
value=[ABCDE, DEF, ESO4SAP] to value=[List(ABCDE, EFGH, ESO4SAP)] and the filter does not work.

As I mentioned, I tried a lot of different list, tried list.toIterator but nothing seems to work for converting the list data structure to a list of values TItem... or Iterable

This is the list of Imports for the mongoDB driver

```
import org.mongodb.scala.connection.ClusterSettings
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject
import com.mongodb.client.model.{FindOneAndReplaceOptions, FindOneAndUpdateOptions}
import org.mongodb.scala.ServerAddress
import org.mongodb.scala._
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.{BsonDocument, conversions}
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Filters._
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Updates._
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the signature of [`Filters#in`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.1/scaladoc/org/mongodb/scala/model/Filters$.html#in[TItem](fieldName:String,values:TItem*):org.mongodb.scala.bson.conversions.Bson), the `values` parameter is varargs.  This is how it supports syntax passing an arbitrary number of arguments, like this:

```
scala> in(EventItem, "ABCDE", "DEF", "ESO4SAP")
res1: org.mongodb.scala.bson.conversions.Bson = Operator Filter{fieldName='EventItem', operator='$in',
value=[ABCDE, DEF, ESO4SAP]}
```

However, in your case, you have a collection, such as a Scala `List`, that you want to build up with variable values, and then pass to `in`.  Doing that directly, `in` ends up interpreting `values` as a single value, which is the `List` itself containing the elements.

```
scala> val ListValidItems = List("ABCDE", "DEF", "ESO4SAP")
ListValidItems: List[String] = List(ABCDE, DEF, ESO4SAP)

scala> in(EventItem, ListValidItems)
res2: org.mongodb.scala.bson.conversions.Bson = Operator Filter{fieldName='EventItem', operator='$in',
value=[List(ABCDE, DEF, ESO4SAP)]}
```

It requires some extra syntax (`ListValidItems:_*`) to "unroll" the collection for passing its individual elements as varargs:

```
scala> in(EventItem, ListValidItems:_*)
res4: org.mongodb.scala.bson.conversions.Bson = Operator Filter{fieldName='EventItem', operator='$in',
value=[ABCDE, DEF, ESO4SAP]}
```

The Scala documentation on [Types](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html) discusses this, in particular the section on [Ascription](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#ascription).

Earlier, it appeared you were attempting to call the Java API from within the Scala code, indicated by the presence of the Java method signatures in your question statement:

```
public static <TItem> Bson in(String fieldName,
                              TItem... values)

public static <TItem> Bson in(String fieldName,
                              Iterable<TItem> values)
```

If that was what you were trying to do, then you could prepare the `ListValidItems` as your Scala collection of choice and then convert to an equivalent Java collection before passing to `in`.  The Java collection will implement the Java `Iterable` interface.

The easiest way to do this is using the [`JavaConverters`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.0/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html) object that is included in Scala.  If you import it, then it will add extension methods to the collection classes to support the conversion.  Here is a demonstration in the REPL.

```
scala> // Import converters.

scala> import collection.JavaConverters._
import collection.JavaConverters._

scala> // Create Scala List.

scala> val ListValidItems = List("ABCDE", "DEF", "ESO4SAP")
ListValidItems: List[String] = List(ABCDE, DEF, ESO4SAP)

scala> // Convert to Java List.

scala> val ListValidItemsConverted = ListValidItems.asJava
ListValidItemsConverted: java.util.List[String] = [ABCDE, DEF, ESO4SAP]

scala> // Prove that it is a Java Iterable.

scala> ListValidItemsConverted.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Iterable[java.lang.String]]
res8: Iterable[String] = [ABCDE, DEF, ESO4SAP]
```

For more details, see [Conversions Between Java and Scala Collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html) in the [Scala Guides and Overviews](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/).

Comment: I just tried that. What I get now is a list of one element, the element being the list



Operator Filter{fieldName='billing_event.action.resources.item', operator='$in', value=[[ABCDE, EFGH, ESO4SAP]]}



The filter fails because it is not [ABCDE, EFGH, ESO4SAP], but [[ABCDE, EFGH, ESO4SAP]]

Comment: Can you please update your question, listing out all of the `import` statements for anything under `com.mongodb`?

Comment: added all the imports for the mongoDB driver
thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  Possibly this was actually a problem with usage of Scala varargs syntax.  If `ListValidItems` is a Scala `List`, then can you please try `in(EventItem, ListValidItems:_*)`?  If that works, then I'll update my answer to explain what is happening.

Comment: That worked! I tried with the scala lists but didn't work, but it does when I convert my list to a Java list and then pass the ListValidItems:_*. Update your answer so I can upvote it. Many thanks!!!!

Comment: Glad to hear this helped!  I have updated the answer.  The new information is at the top, and I retained the old information about passing from Scala to the Java API below that, just in case it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import org.bson.Document
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.BsonDocument
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.conversions.Bson
import org.mongodb.scala.{FindObservable, MongoClient, MongoCollection, MongoDatabase, Observer, Subscription}

val client: MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")
val db: MongoDatabase = client.getDatabase("test")
val dbColl: MongoCollection[Document] = db.getCollection[Document]("md" + TaskContext.getPartitionId)
val ids: List[String] = List("A","B","C")  
val listStr: String = ids.map(o => "\"" + o + "\"").distinct.mkString(",")
val filterStr = """{_id:{$in:""" + s"""[$listStr]}}"""
val filterDoc: Document = Document.parse(filterStr)
val obs: FindObservable[Document] = dbColl.find(filterDoc)
val documents: Seq[Document] = Await.result(obs.toFuture(), Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
```

This works.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Code-only answers aren't as useful as code with explanatory text, especially when a question is as old as this one it is often instructive to explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers.